# Using parameterized tests with "ExpectedResult" and following Osherove's 3-part naming convention

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I really like Roy Osherove's 3-part naming convention for naming unit tests:

> [UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]

Which to me means something like this (even when using parameterized inputs):

```
[TestCase("user1")]
[TestCase("user2")]
public void SayHello_OnExistingUser_ReturnsHelloMessage(string username) 
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello " + username, SayHello(username));
}

[TestCase("badusername")]
[TestCase("")]
public void SayHello_OnNonExistingUser_ReturnsNull(string username) 
{
    Assert.IsNull(SayHello(username));
}
```

However, this is a bit tricky when using parameterized unit tests **with specified expected result per test case**, such as:

```
[TestCase("user1", ExpectedResult = "Hello user1")]
[TestCase("user2", ExpectedResult = "Hello user2")]
[TestCase("badusername", ExpectedResult = null)]
[TestCase("", ExpectedResult = null)]
public void TESTNAMEHERE(string username)
{
    return SayHello(username);
}
```

With parameters for both the *StateUnderTest* and *ExpectedBehavior* it is less obvious what the test name should be.  I have heard suggestions to NOT use the "expected result" in TestCase for this reason, but it seems like a potentially great functionality that could simplify the test code.

I'd like to hear some suggestions for how to do this.  Abandon ExpectedResult for the sake of unit test naming clarity?  Or trade some clarity for test code brevity?

Answer (score 1):

ExpectedResult is very handy and doesn't *always* violate the principles of good naming. But sometimes it does, in which case your code is trying to tell you something.

For the successful cases, a name like SayHello_OnExistingUser_ReturnsExpectedGreeting will work.

For the non-successful cases, SayHello_OnNonExistingUser_ReturnsNull will also work.

It's only by trying to combine what are logically two different tests in to one that you get into trouble. So don't do that. The fact that the same *code* can be used to write two entirely different (logically) different tests is simply an accident.

Comment: I see.  That's not a bad way to think about it. In any given scenario, we are either expecting a good/successful thing to occur, or a bad/non-successful thing to occur, so it makes sense to have [at least] two unit tests, even if the test code itself is mostly (or even completely) the same.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, purpose of Roy Osherove's naming idea was faster see summary of failed test without explicitly open the details of test method.

So `NUnit`'s `TestCaseAttribute` has a property `TestName`. Value of that property will be used as test name in the test explorer.

Or use more generic name for the test, for example:
`MyMethod_TestCaseInputValues_ReturnCorrespondentValue`

Comment: Hmm, wasn't aware of the TestName property on TestCaseAttribute. I guess I need to take a closer look at that. Thanks!